# Check if a blur event of an input field is fired while clicking on a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, events

I have an input field and two radio buttons. I would like to evaluate the form data whenever the form has changed. Strictly speaking, I want to react to the blur event of the input field. However, there is a situation where a user enters a value in the input field and (without pressing enter or clicking anywhere with the mouse) clicks directly on the radio buttons. Now there is the effect that the radio buttons are visually displayed to the user as checked, but the blur event is already fired. At this point, no radio button was technically checked yet.

For technical reasons, however, the radio selection must already exist in the form.

So my question is: Is it possible to check at the blur event whether the user has clicked on a radio button? It is about firing the event afterwards in such a special case (so that the selection of the radio button can be included in an evaluation).

*(By the way: I use angular for my project. Just in case this could make a difference.)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough info here. Post some code.

Comment: You could always wrap the code in the (blur) method that gets called in a setTimeout of 0 seconds (or a small amount of time if it makes a differenc), so that it runs in the next event cycle. Not sure if it would cause any unwanted side effects or not, but it would be the most straightforward first step I'd try.